# Rename PHP session cookie with __Secure-/__Host- prefix

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, session, cookies

I'm trying to rename my PHP session cookie from `PHPSESSID` to `__Secure-PHPSESSID` as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Examples.

Since PHP does not offer this mechanism, I am doing it through Apache server configuration:

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie ^__Secure-PHPSESSID(.*)$ PHPSESSID$1
Header edit Set-Cookie ^PHPSESSID(.*)$ __Secure-PHPSESSID$1
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)(?<!SameSite=Strict)(?<!SameSite=Lax)$ "$1;SameSite=Lax"
```

This works correctly in Firefox, Edge, and Safari, but not Chrome. On Chrome, I can see that the cookie is set with the correct name and flags but I cannot log in to my site.

Upon login, the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['internal']['user_name'])` is `NULL` on Chrome but shows the correct username on Firefox and other browsers. I can also see that the session ID is being regenerated every time I try to log in and the value is set in the `__Secure-PHPSESSID` cookie.

I tried removing the `SameSite` flag (line 3 above) and it still does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the site under HTTPS?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, the site is fully HTTPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [Cookie Prefixes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-prefixes-00) but PHP should support it [out of the box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php):

```
<?php

session_name('__Secure-PHPSESSID');
session_start();
```

[image: Set-Cookie]

Comment: The documentation for that method says "It should contain only alphanumeric characters". Are there any issues with having characters like `_` and `-` in the session name?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Good point. I suspect it has to do with good old [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), which are of course no longer relevant but affected the overall design back in the day. I have the feeling that it should be safe now but I don't have an official source.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 cookie name seems to be good: _If a cookie's name begins with "__Secure-"_ ...  https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-prefixes-00#section-3.1

Answer (score 8):

PHP does indeed offer this mechanism. You can change it in `php.ini`.  Just set this and restart the site:

```ini
session.name = __Secure-PHPSESSID
```

To confirm it's right, restart your browser to clear previous session cookies.

As for Chrome not letting you log in, this page may give you some clues (see "Option Secure" and "Prefixes" sections): https://www.mon-code.net/post/108/secure-cookie-of-you-web-application-with-php-or-symfony

> They are not well known, but supported by all browsers except those of
> Microsoft. With prefixes, it's possible to force the browser to not
> accept a cookie if it's misconfigured. There are two prefixes
> "`__Secure-`" and "`__Host-`".
> `__Secure-` forces the developer to add the secure flag to his cookie, otherwise it will be ignored by the browser.
>
> ```
> setcookie('__Secure-user_id', 10, 0, '/', 'orion.dev', true);
> ```
>
> `__Host-` is more restrictive, cookie must have the secure flag but also path to root and blank domain.
>
> ```
> setcookie('__Host-user_id', 10, 0, '/', '', true);
> ```

Comment: I have added to my `php.ini` `session.name = __HOST-PHPSESSID` is that correct? It doesn't seem to cause any issues but I'm not sure that's right because my website runs on a subdomain...so how does that work?

Comment: It's kind of surprising how little mention there is of this online. Here is a second reference: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/02/09/cookie-prefixes/#making-cookies-more-secure

Comment: also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#cookie_prefixes

Answer (score 3):

You can actually achieve it using PHP, changing [`session.name`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) parameter. You can do it:

1. using [`session_name()`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) in your PHP script
2. in `.htaccess` file
3. directly into CPanel table that shows PHP options (if you run CPanel)

Examples:

```
// Example way 1
session_name('Secure-PHPSESSID');
session_start();

// Example way 2
php_value session.name "Secure-PHPSESSID"
```

Comment: The prefix must be *exactly* `__Secure-`. What you have suggested is just a regular PHP session name, not an official cookie prefix that will trigger the [RFC6265bis](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-06) behaviour.